# How can I update the meta tags in WordPress using actions or filters?

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

I have read a little about actions and filters in WordPress so I know that filters are used to modify the data while actions are used to do something at a specific events.

The Yoast SEO plugin offers some [actions and filters](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) to developers in order to update the output meta tags.

I need to make some changes to the `og:title` tag and `twitter:title` but there is no filter to update these two particular tags. Is there any way to make the changes using Actions?

Here is what I would have done with Filters:

```
function change_opengraph_title( $title ) {
    return str_replace('Initial', 'Replacement', $title);
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'change_opengraph_title', 10, 1 );
```

Ofcourse, there is no `wpseo_opengraph_title` filter so it won't work. How can I get around that?

The plugin does offer two relevant actions:

**wpseo_head** Runs at the end of the output of all SEO meta tags by the plugin, before the closing debug comment.

**wpseo_opengraph** Runs at the end of the output of OpenGraph meta tags by the plugin, before the closing debug comment.

How can I use them to change the `og:title` tags? Is there any other way to update (og) or general meta tags in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_opengraph_title( $title ) {
    return str_replace('Initial', 'Replacement', $title);
}
apply_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'change_opengraph_title', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks Osama but how does this work? The plugin does not offer a `wpseo_opengraph_title` filter. :)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131786/difference-between-add-filter-and-apply-filters